# Create a instance of class and pass to c++ code

Tags: python, c++

I have a class called entity which like this:

```
class entity {
public:
 entity();
virtual ~entity();
virtual void draw();
virtual void init();

protected:
std::string name;
};
```

now I want to create an instance of the class in python,then load it back to c++,is it posibile to write a function like this:

```
entity* loadEntityFromPython(char *pythonscript);
```

Comment: [The Boost Python library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) might be good.

Comment: I was much too slow, sorry for the repost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give boost::python a try. It generates python-bindings for c++ code to use it in python. And of course it is also possible to generate python-bindings for C++-based classes. Please have a look into the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html